# How to merge equal opening hours on consecutive days?

Tags: c#

I am trying to merge equal opening hours on consecutive days.

```
public class AgendaDay {
    public string Day;
    public string AM;
    public string PM;

    public AgendaDay(string day, string aM, string pM)
    {
        Day = day;
        AM = aM;
        PM = pM;
    }
}

var agenda = new List<AgendaDay>() {
    new AgendaDay("Mon", "0900-1200", "1400-1700"),
    new AgendaDay("Tue", "0900-1200", "1400-1700"),
    new AgendaDay("Wed", "", "1400-1700"),
    new AgendaDay("Thu", "0900-1200", "1400-1700"),
    new AgendaDay("Fri", "0900-1200", "1400-1700"),
    new AgendaDay("Sat", "0900-1200", ""),
    null
};
```

Reducing it to :

```
var expected = @"Mon-Tue: 09H00-12H00 / 14H00-17H00 
Wed: 14H00-17H00
Thu-Fri: 09H00-12H00 / 14H00-17H00  
Sat: 09H00-12H00";
```

For now I have:

```
public class ShortAgendaDay
{
    public List<string> Days;
    public string AM;
    public string PM;
    public ShortAgendaDay(List<string> days, string aM, string pM)
    {
        Days = days;
        AM = aM;
        PM = pM;
    }
}

private static string ShrinkOpenningHour( List<AgendaDay> agenda)
{
    var temp = agenda.Where(x=> x!=null).ToArray();        
    List<ShortAgendaDay> sum = new List<ShortAgendaDay>();

    for (var i = 0; i < temp.Count(); i++)
    {
        if (i == 0) continue;

        var last = temp[i - 1];
        var curr = temp[i];
        if (last.AM == curr.AM && last.PM == curr.PM) {

        }
    }

    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

My idea was to reduce it to a list like:

```
{ 
    day:["Mon","Tue"],
    hour: "09H00-12H00 / 14H00-17H00"
},
{ 
    day:["Wed"],
    hour:"14H00-17H00"
},
{ 
    day:["Thu","Fri"],
    hour:"09H00-12H00 / 14H00-17H00"
}
```

Then to take only the First and the Last from the list of Day.

The format from "0900-1200" to "09h00-12h00" is not an issue you can ignore it in your answer.
"0900-1400", "1400-1700" is only equals to "0900-1400", "1400-1700". there is no trick like "0900-1000", "1000-1700". Overlapping timestamp do not really matter. It's a string and must be handled as a string, not timestamps with overlapping timespans.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: From agenda declaration to Expected result @TimSchmelter

Comment: Yes Equals. sorry for my English. @TimSchmelter. but similar looks like the right word has they are alomost the same hour are equals but days are different.

Comment: @xdtTransform So by *similar*, do you mean *equal* hours and *consecutive* days (Mon-Fri), or *any* days (Mon, Wed, Sub)?

Comment: In your last example, you probably meant to use `"Fri"` instead of `"Wed"`

Comment: @Rotem, the question is How do I merge the consecutive "similar" day. I don't know how to make a clear sentence about this. .. Mergin `List<a,b,c>` into `List<List<a>,b,c>` when `b` and `c` are equals only for consecutive entry. does this sound clearer?

Comment: @xdtTransform What happens if e.g. `Sun`, `Mon` and `Wed` have the same hours but `Tue` has different hours?

Comment: @xdtTransform The special case of having two opening hours per day leaves a lot open to interpretation. Your examples are not very exhaustive, you might want to come up with a *very* explicit ruleset to handle **all** edge-cases.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer, `"0900-1400", "1400-1700"` is only equals to  `"0900-1400", "1400-1700"`. there is no trick like  `"0900-1000", "1000-1700"`. adding this information too

Comment: Don't store information together packed into strings. It's far easier to work with when you have a discrete property for each piece of information. It removes the trouble of needing to parse the values to get the information you need.

Comment: @xdtTransform From the looks of it, you simply want to merge keys (day of week) while the value (opening hours) are an exact match. (Find Ranges)

Comment: @xdtTransform To be honest, while I now understand what you are trying to do from a technical perspective, I don't understand it from a UX perspective. Opening hours are so much easier to read when they just list all weekdays with separate entries (even Google does it that way).

Comment: I have a nuget package, [Linqy](https://www.nuget.org/packages/linqy/) that could do this for you easily: `agenda.GroupIf((d1, d2) => d1.AM == d2.AM && d1.PM == d2.PM)`

Comment: Started writing a solution but the question is closed. You can find it here - https://dotnetfiddle.net/YzmMDF

Comment: @Carra Question is reopened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the merging:

```
private string ShrinkOpenningHour(List<AgendaDay> agenda)
{
    var temp = agenda.Where(x => x != null).ToArray();
    List<ShortAgendaDay> sum = new List<ShortAgendaDay>();

    for (var i = 0; i < temp.Count(); i++)
    {
        if (i == 0 || (temp[i - 1].heureAM == temp[i].heureAM && temp[i - 1].heurePM == temp[i].heurePM))
        {
            var existingEntry = sum.Where(x => x.AM == temp[i].heureAM && x.PM == temp[i].heurePM);
            if (existingEntry.Count() == 1)
            {
                existingEntry.First().Days.Add(temp[i].jour);
            }
            else
            {
                sum.Add(new ShortAgendaDay(new List<string>() { temp[i].jour }, temp[i].heureAM, temp[i].heurePM));
            }
        }
    }

    return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, sum.Select(x => FormatHorraire(x)));
}
```

And as bonus the formating:

```
private string FormatHorraire(ShortAgendaDay x)
{
    string days = string.Join(" - ", new String[] { x.Days.First(), x.Days.Last() }.Where(ar => ar != null).Distinct());
    string hour = FormatHorraire(x.AM, x.PM);
    return days + " : " + hour;
}

private string FormatHorraire(string am, string pm)
{
    return string.Join(" / ", new string[] { am, pm }.Where(y => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(y) && y.Length > 7).Select(y => y.Insert(2, "H").Insert(8, "H")));
}
```